# Json polymorphism with Jackson and Json without wrapper object

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I have the following Java beans:

```
    /**
     * The top container. It uses generics.
     */
    public class Response {
      @JsonTypeInfo(
          use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
          include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT,
          property = "type"
      )
      @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "AContent", value = A.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "BContent", value = B.class),        
      })  
      private E object;
    }

    /**
     * First type
     */ 
    @JsonRootName("AContent")
    public class A {
        ...
    }

    /**
     * Second type
     */ 
    @JsonRootName("BContent")
    public class B {
        ...
    }
```

When request are processed, I just expect the following output:

```
{
    AContent: { ...}
}
```

However, I get the following output:

```
{
    object: {
        AContent: { ...}
    }
}
```

The element "AContent" is wrapped into the object element. I don't want a wrapper object for generic. I also don't want to set object type directly inside the generic object.

I would like to output the "AContent" directly inside the root element.

How can we achieve that with Jackson ?

Thanks you in advance for you help.

Best regards,

Yellow duck

Comment: As for serializing you can always use custom serializer that skips _Request_ and goes straight to _object_ but deserializing this is trickier.

Comment: I would like to let jersey/jackson automatically serialize the object.

Is it possible to achieve that with jackson annotation ?

Comment: There is another solution if you can afford to introduce base entity of _A_ and _B_.

Comment: I could introduce a base entity of A and B.

What is this solution?

Could you provide an example please ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you can provide base entity for A and B the solution will be:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ResponseSerializer.class)
public class Response<T> {
    private T object;  
    ...
}
```

Base entity (others must extend it):

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "AContent", value = EntityA.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "BContent", value = EntityB.class),
})
public class Entity {
    ...
}
```

And serializer:

```
public class ResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Response> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Response value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Class<?> responseClass = value.getObject().getClass();
        JavaType responseJavaType = serializers.constructType(responseClass);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName(serializers.findTypeSerializer(responseJavaType).getTypeIdResolver().idFromValue(value.getObject()));
        serializers.findValueSerializer(responseClass).serialize(value.getObject(), gen, serializers);
        /* Here you must manually serialize other properties */
        /* Like gen.writeStringField("property", value.getProperty()); */
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

P.S. I removed extra annotations you had that made no difference to output.

Comment: Thank you very much chimmi. 

It works perfectly with common base entity with JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations and with the JsonValue annotation on the getObject() method.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution (jsonValue annotation): I could not see others properties in the Request bean anymore.

For example, in the Request class, if I add a new attribute, it will not be displayed in the json result.

Comment: @yellowduck Your question have no indication that there are other properties in _Response_, that's why I thought _JsonValue_ is enough. Anyway, Ive replaced my answer with one using custom serializer, at least with this you can serialize additional properties manually. And, Im afraid this is the best solution you can get, atleast best I can do.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better solution but it works by extending JsonSerializer. 

Thank you @chimmi for your help. You are great

Comment: @yellowduck If my solution works for you, consider accepting my answer